# Knex types with joins

Tags: typescript, knex.js

I am trying to use Knex and inspect the types of the result so for instance

```
const entries = await trx<Table_Type>('table')
.select(
   trx.ref('id').withSchema('table'),
   trx.ref('name').withSchema('table'),
)
```

The entries type is correct for each column selected.

But once I try to make a join like this

```
.leftJoin<Table2_Type>('table2', 'table.id', 'table2.table1_id')
```

All types are marked as never, am I missing something ?

```
const entries = await trx<Table_Type>('table')
.select(
   trx.ref('id').withSchema('table'),
   trx.ref('name').withSchema('table'),
)
.leftJoin<Table2_Type>('table2', 'table.id', 'table2.table1_id')
```

Expected entries to have type of `{id: number, name: string}`

Gotentries of type `{id: never, name: never}`

Comment: so how does `Table_Type` look like?

Comment: it's an exported type of like `export type Table_Type = id: number; name: string;`